# RaisePostDataChangedEvent called on callbacks too?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, callback, postback

I'm debugging some weird behavior in a ASP.NET webforms app. I've narrowed it down to something I find peculiar: A control which implements `IPostBackDataHandler` has it's `RaisePostDataChangedEvent` called even if it's a callback from another control. I've reproduced this in a dummy test page.

Information on how it SHOULD be is scarce. I've found only [one page](http://nilsnaegele.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/asp-net-page-life-cycle/) which seems to imply that it's only called on postbacks, and not on callbacks.

Is this how it should be? Has it always been so?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging around in ASP.NET source code I think I can say with certainty - **that's how it's always been**.

Awesome. I shudder to think how many places in the application have subtle flaws because of this. It's a good thing we're on the path of replacing it all with MVC.